# Finding solutions to $ x^x = 2x$

Tags: analysis, tetration, lambert-w

A friend claims it isn't possible to find a closed form for the smaller positive real solution of $x^x = 2x$. Numerically we have seen that $0.346...$ and $2$ are solutions, but are failing to do anything but approximate the first solution.

The first attempt to find a closed form was using the same trick as solving
$$x^{x^{x^x...}} = 2$$
Where raising $x$ to the power of both sides gives:
$$x^{x^{x^x...}} = x^2$$

$$\Rightarrow 2 = x^2 $$
$$\Rightarrow x = \sqrt{2}$$

But without an infinite power tower we got nowhere.

We know $f(z) = z^z$ is analytic with inverse $f^{-1}(z) = e^{W(ln(z))}$ where $W(z)$ is the Lambert-W function, But $x = e^{W(ln(2x))}$ doesn't seem any better.

I am just wondering how to approach such a problem.

Comment: Hint: Take the natural log of both sides and see what you get

Comment: @ASKASK That hint doesn't lead anywhere special. $(x - 1)\log_2 x = 1$

Comment: There is a [series solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B1%2Fn%21+D%5B2%5E%28n%2Fx%29%2C%7Bx%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C8%7D%5D%2Cx%3D-1.0) for which the derivatives can be expanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^x=2x$$
$$e^{\ln(x)x}=2x$$

Your equation is an equation of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). It's an algebraic equation in dependence of $e^{\ln(x)x}$ and $x$. Because the terms $e^{\ln(x)x},x$ are algebraically independent and the equation is irreducible, we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by only elementary operations (means elementary functions).
I don't know if the equation has solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

$$\ln(x)x=\ln(2x)$$
$x\to e^t$:
$$te^t=\ln(2)+t$$
$$\frac{t}{\ln(2)+t}e^t=1$$
$$\frac{t}{t-(-\ln(2))}e^t=1$$

We see, your equation cannot be solved in terms of Lambert W but in terms of Generalized Lambert W.

$$t=W\left(^{\ \ \ \ \ \ 0}_{-\ln(2)};1\right)$$
$$x=e^{W\left(^{\ \ \ \ \ \ 0}_{-\ln(2)};1\right)}$$

The inverse relation of your kind of equations is what Mezö et al. call $r$-Lambert function. They write:
"Depending on the parameter $r$, the $r$-Lambert function has one, two or three real branches and so the above equations can have one, two or three solutions"

So we have a closed form for $x$, and the representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Comment: Superbly done! I'm surprised someone found and answered the question after 8 years. Looking back Mező's original submission for the Generalized Lambert W has been available since the time of asking, if only by a few months prior.

Answer (score 3):

Today and as far as I know about special functions, there is no closed form for the non-trivial root of $x^x=2x$, even with the LambertW function. This would require a more advanced or more general special function which is not defined and referenced yet.

As already mentioned, in practice the root $x\simeq 0.3456323$ is obtained thanks to numerical calculus.

Another way, but not useful in practice because more complicated, is the inversion of function in terms of series : $x^x=2x$ is equivalent to $x^{x-1}=2$ and to $(x-1)\ln(x)=\ln(2)$

Consider the function $y=(x-1)\ln(x)$ . The serie expansion and inversion, which is a booring calculus, leads to :
$$x=1-y^{1/2}+\frac{1}{4}y+\frac{1}{96}y^{3/2}-\frac{59}{92160}y^{5/2}-\frac{1}{92880}y^{3}-\frac{2783}{20643840}y^{7/2}-\frac{1}{24192}y^{4}-\frac{1060117}{118908518400}y^{9/2}-\frac{1}{4838400}y^{5}+...$$
In the present case $y=\ln(2)$ Puting it into the preceeding equation yields to :
$$x\simeq 0.346323$$

Answer (score 2):

**I will give you an example problem:**

An exponential tetration is where $x$ is exponentiated by itself $n$ times, as for example

$$_{ }^{ 4 }{ x }={ x }^{ {\displaystyle x }^{ {\displaystyle x }^{\displaystyle x } } }$$

As $n$ approaches $\infty$, then for some $0$, the function bifurcates at point $B$, splitting into the upper branch where $n$ is even and the lower branch where $n$ is odd, even though in both cases, $n$ approaches $\infty$ .

Point $A$ is the origin $(0,0)$ and point $C$ is $(0,1)$

Let $T$ be the area of $ABC$ as defined by the upper and lower branches, and the line $x=0$

***How do you Solve this?***

This problem is a little easier to solve if we looked at the function(s) in the other way. The curve as defined by the upper and lower branches, joining at point $B,$ can alternatively be described by the implicit equation

$${ x }^{ { \displaystyle x }^{\displaystyle y } }-y=0$$

where $x(y)$ arches smoothly from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$. Then any one of several possible numerical integration methods can be used, once we have an exact implicit equation. For example, given a valuie $0\le y\le 1$, numerically determine $x$ using the secant method, and use it as a data point for numerical integration.

The critical point $B$ is
$$\left( \dfrac { 1 }{ { e }^{ e } } ,\dfrac { 1 }{ e } \right) $$

A more straightforward way to numerically integrate this is to use a loop to exponentially tetrate $0\le x\le { e }^{ -e } $ for some very large $2n$ and $2n+1$, and use the difference as a data point for numerical integration.

Thus, one can check the numerical results from both methods for confidence in final accuracy.

Note: The other critical point for the infinite exponential tetration is
$$({ e }^{ \frac { 1 }{\displaystyle e } },e)$$

which is the limit of convergence, i.e., for $x>{ e }^{ \frac { 1 }{ e } }$ it does not converge

Answer (score 0):

*(previous approach deleted,for archiving matters see edit-history)*

Here is a list of 10 new solutions, internal precision 200 dec digits:

```
         x                                      |x^x-2x |
    ---------------------------------------  ----------------------  
 0     2.000000000000000                      0.0                     known solution
 1     3.116777334842701+3.115627209097009*I  8.249384166600113E-72   new solutions ...
 2     3.944366616159206+5.234957142265235*I  1.834796992244078E-88
 3     4.632829407543712+7.121955754816833*I  2.116951288747908E-98
 4     5.245455860616367+8.882459562041511*I  2.042549956851917E-105
 5     5.808250013483836+10.55849284332458*I  8.488793906217181E-111
 6     6.334925551361967+12.17222101970428*I  3.863116441982432E-115
 7     6.833781384222634+13.73716605764375*I  9.156097713919543E-119
 8     7.310302197236129+15.26235645509978*I  7.227764889511877E-122
 9     7.768342845867481+16.75420564534052*I  1.423061553268047E-124
10     8.210738840969926+18.21748045660466*I  5.736096368440588E-127
```

A q&d Pari/GP-routine:

```
 lg2 = log(2) ; \\ put it into a constant to avaoid recomputations
 for(c=0,10, 
       x=1+I; \\ just any complex initialization
       for(k=1,250,
               x = (lg2+ c*2*Pi*I)/log(x)+1
          );
       print( x, "  ", abs(x^x - 2*x));
      );
```

A picture showing the first few complex zeros of $f(x)=x^x - 2x$. The green lines mark the zeros of the real part, the red lines that of the imaginary part, and where they cross (light color, and a marker) we have a complex zero. The image suggests, that we have one "linear" list of zeros as indicated in the numerical list above, approximating to some curve growing to linear shape.
*Note, there are the two known zeros on the real axis ($x=2$,$ x \approx 0.34$)*

[image]